# Need help understanding why my code works the way it does (JS)

Tags: javascript

I created this code as a part of a course I'm following to learn JS, I'm a beginner so I don't quite understand what's going on here. The part of the code in question is at the end where it states '1 bottle 'instead of '1 bottles' and '0 bottles' instead of '0 bottle', which is correct, but I'm not sure how. If I take the bottom code snippet of 'console.log (numberOfBottles + " " + bottleWord + " of beer on the wall.");', and place it above the 'If' statements, '1 bottle' turns to '1 bottles' and '0 bottles' turns to '0 bottle', which is wrong. But, I don't understand what's causing it to change and why. I hope I've explained this clearly enough, any help would be appreciated.

```js
function beerSong() {
var numberOfBottles = 99;
var bottleWord="bottles";

while (numberOfBottles>0) {

   console.log (numberOfBottles + " " + bottleWord + " of beer on the wall, " + numberOfBottles + " " + bottleWord + " of beer. Take 1 down, pass it around,");

   numberOfBottles--;


   if (numberOfBottles===1){
  bottleWord="bottle";
   }
   if (numberOfBottles===0){
     bottleWord="bottles";
   }

   console.log (numberOfBottles + " " + bottleWord + " of beer on the wall.");
   
}
}

beerSong();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By anticipating the `if` statements before the `numberOfBottles--;` line you are checking the quantity of the variable before decreasing it.

Using your code as an example and considering the loop cycle where `numberOfBottles` is equal to 2 at the beginning:

```
...
    // Here numberOfBottles is 2
    numberOfBottles--;

    // Here numberOfBottles is 1
    if (numberOfBottles===1) {
        // bottleWord gets updated to "bottle"
        bottleWord="bottle";
    }
    if (numberOfBottles===0) {
        bottleWord="bottles";
    }

    // This will print: "1 bottle of beer on the wall."
    console.log (numberOfBottles + " " + bottleWord + " of beer on the wall.");
...

...
    // Here numberOfBottles is 2, bottleWord doesn't get update since it's not 1 or 0
    if (numberOfBottles===1) {
        bottleWord="bottle";
    }
    if (numberOfBottles===0) {
        bottleWord="bottles";
    }

    numberOfBottles--;

    // Here numberOfBottles is 1

    // This will print: "1 bottles of beer on the wall."
    console.log (numberOfBottles + " " + bottleWord + " of beer on the wall.");
...
```